# Convert 32bit binary to base10

Tags: ruby

Why does

```
111111111111111111111111111110.to_s(10)
```

return

```
"111111111111111111111111111110"
```

instead of the following?

```
4294967294
```

Comment: Why would you expect `4294967294`? It isn't even a string. Even if you meant a string, why would you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `111111111111111111111111111110` is a base 10 integer. Try this:

```
0b11111111111111111111111111111110.to_s
# => "4294967294"
```

Note the `0b` prefix for binary.

Or, perhaps what you want is:

```
11111111111111111111111111111110.to_s.to_i(2).to_s
# => "4294967294"
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Yu Hao](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27915812/2767755) mentioned what was the issue, I wouldn't repeat it again. I just shown here, how can we get the result other-way in Ruby using [`Kernel#sprintf`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) as :

```
sprintf("%d", 0b11111111111111111111111111111110)
# => "4294967294"
```

> [When typing numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_number_format#Octal_and_hex_number_display) formatting characters is used to describe the number system, for example `000_0000B` or `0b000_00000` for **binary** and `0F8H` or `0xf8` for **hexadecimal** numbers. By default the number is treated as *decimal* number.

Comment: Please share comments for downvoting.

Comment: Not my downvote...but why break out `sprintf` for something so simple?  And more importantly, why not mention what you actually fixed (adding the `0b` prefix)?  This answer would be just as broken as the OP's code without that little tidbit.

Comment: @cHao Great! Can you explain - _This answer would be just as broken as the OP's code without that little tidbit._ what do you mean? I just tried to show another way to solve this problem that is the use of `sprintf`. And trust me `sprintf` is really another standard and simple way in Ruby. We use it frequently.

Comment: I mean, if you'd said `sprintf("%d", 111111111111111111111111111110)` (without the prefix, just as the OP was doing), you'd have gotten the wrong answer too.  It's that `0b` that actually makes the code work...and you just kinda sneak it in without even mentioning it.  :)

Comment: @cHao I was searching for a good link to support the `0b` context. In between got the punishment. :)